# Showing progress from a task that's runnning in a referenced assembly

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have a WPF project that references a separate assembly.  In the referenced assembly I have a class that is responsible for extracting some data from text files.  Lets say it reads the file line by line, so I can calculate the percentage complete by comparing what line it's on to the total lines.

In the WPF application I have a progress bar and created a data binding to a ViewModel property to store the progress.

How do I get the progress from the external assembly to update the ViewModel property so that my progress bar 'view' gets updated in the UI?

**BTW**:  The referenced assembly, I have access to the source and can change/add code to it.  Everything is .NET 4.5 or higher.

Comment: How does the external assembly report its progress?

Comment: @Clint it doesn't yet, I'm not sure how to communicate that to the UI side.  I mean I can calculate it, but don't know what to do with the value after that.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like a fit for [IProgress](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh138298(v=vs.110).aspx).

[Here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2012/06/06/async-in-4-5-enabling-progress-and-cancellation-in-async-apis/) is a sample of how it can be used.

Some pseudo code:

```
public void DoWorkWithFile(IProgress<double> progress)
{
    var lines = File.ReadAllLines("path to a file");
    for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
    {
        // do stuff with the line
        progress.Report(100 * i / (double)lines.Length);
    }
}
```

Note that `ReadAllLines` will consume a lot of memory if the file is big so it should not be used if so.

An alternative if you happen to know the number of lines in the file:

```
public async Task DoWorkWithFileAsync(IProgress<double> progress)
{
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead("path to a file")))
    {
        var totalLines = (double)55; // Assuming you know it
        var lineNo = 0;
        string line;
        while ((line = await reader.ReadLineAsync().ConfigureAwait(false)) != null)
        {
            // do stuff with the line
            lineNo++;
            progress.Report(100 * lineNo / totalLines);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As per your edit explaining you can make changes to the code in the other assembly, I would recommend going for an approach I'm partial to:

```
// This would be in the external assembly
public MyReturnValue ProcessFile(Action<double> progressDelegate)
{
    foreach(var line in file)
    {
        progressDelegate?.Invoke(myCalculatedProgress)
    }
}

// This would be in the app

var progDelegate = new Action<double>((progress) => ViewModel.Progress = progress);
ExternalLibrary.ProcessFile(progDelegate);
```

Of course, this is just something I quickly threw together and will need adapting to your project, but this is something I used to use at a previous employer on fairly big WPF projects and it worked pretty well.

You'll need to take care of all the usual suspects like dispatching the update onto the UI thread, but it's all fairly standard.

We also made use of the [IProgress](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh138298(v=vs.110).aspx) interface to pass around actual objects for reporting these things without chucking delegates everywhere; this was in particular used to show a modal dialog when anything called out to a global IProgress scope we used.

Comment: what does the question mark do after progressDelegate in the foreach?  It works without it, I thought it was a typo.

Comment: @erotavlas it's a null condition operator, if the delegate is null, it won't try to call `.Invoke`, hence avoiding an `if(arg) == null` check

Comment: Also I'm having trouble updating the UI, the code is working and the viewmodel variable get's updated at each change, however the UI is frozen and the progress bar doesn't display the value until it's completed (100%)  I'm looking at how to use Dispatcher to update from a different thread.  Any ideas?

Comment: Are you doing the work on a separate thread? If it's doing it all on the UI thread then there'll be no payoff. You could either spin up a separate thread and do the work there, or use the async/await pattern.

Comment: yes ProcessFile method is located in another assembly.  I figured out why the UI is frozen, its as you suggested, I have to use async/await pattern.  So I'll give that a try.

Comment: I mean a separate thread as in `Thread.Start` or `BackgroundWorker`, but yes, you can certainly use the async/await. I'll update my answer to include that.

Comment: (actually, Johan's answer has a good async/await example). Of course the structure will entirely depend on how you read the file and what metric you're using.